# Powershell with ASCII extended code

Tags: powershell

In Powershell version 4.0, I try to launch a process from a script file.

When I try :

```
start-process -FilePath "C:\MyFile.exe" -ArgumentList '"D:\Programmes a installer\MyProgram.ext"'
```

it works perfectly.

But, when I try :

```
start-process -FilePath "C:\MyFile.exe" -ArgumentList '"D:\Programmes à installer\MyProgram.ext"'
```

it doesn't work saying that it can't open the file "D:\Programmes Ã installer\MyProgram.ext". The change is in "Programmes **à** installer" instead of "Programmes a installer".

How to make it work with ASCII extended characters ?

Comment: what happens when you invoke MyFile.exe from CMD with the same args?

Comment: Why are you using " and ' for the path? Try just 'D:\Programmes a installer\MyProgram.ext'

Comment: @AustinFrench I think he does it like that, so the program receives a single argument (i.e. a string with spaces) instead of 3.

Comment: @ Micky Balladelli

The version 2 (with the à) works when I launch it from the Powershell CMD  but it doesn't from a script file.

Comment: @Austin French
It doesn't work otherwise. I have to make the " and the '

Comment: What's the value of `$OutputEncoding` ?

Comment: @Micky Balladelli
The "EncodingName" is US-ASCII and "IsSingleByte" is True.
And I repeat, it works when I launch it directly from the PowerShell command window but it doesn't when I launch it from a script file.

Comment: I just tried with an other computer and it works even when I launch it from the script file ! I think that my computer is guilty.

Comment: Yes, I can't reproduce the problem here. I wrote a quick C# console app to see the arguments, and they are good no matter what I try.

Comment: I tried on a third computer and it's working again. Can't understand why it doesn't on my main computer. I will try a complete reinstallation I think.
Thanks a lot  Micky Balladelli for ur help.